# Contar los objetos o items que devuelve una QUERY en Dynamodb

Tags: c#, dynamodb

tengo una consulta en c#

```
QueryOperationConfig config = new QueryOperationConfig()
 {
  Filter = queryFilter,
  Limit = agrupadoEn,
  ConsistentRead = false,
 };
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(index))
  {
   config.IndexName = index;
  }
 Search search = table.Query(config);

 var total = search.Count;

 List<Document> documentList = new List<Document>();
 do
 {
  documentList = search.GetNextSet();
  foreach (var document in documentList) {
   //TRABAJO CON LOS DOCUMENTOS
  } while (!search.IsDone);
```

***var total = search.Count;***

me devuelve el total de items de esa vuelta (aproximadamente 1500), no el total del QUERY (aproximadamente 19000)

existe una forma de saber el total de objetos que trae la consulta?

Comment: Porque no usas un contador y lo incrementas dentro del `foreach`?

Comment: necesito el valor total antes del `foreach`, para poder mostrar el progreso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes se debe a la cantidad de datos que retorna tu consulta, se limita a 1MB [revisa la documentación](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan), para resolverlo debes hacer una paginación, algo como esto:

```
#Método para obtener todos los usuarios
    @classmethod
    def return_all(cls):
        response = table.scan()
        payload = response['Items']

        #La operación scan() retorna todos los elementos de la tabla 
        #correspondiente, siempre y cuando el tamaño que retorne sea menor a 1MB. 
        #Esto se resuelve paginando los resultados en un bucle
        while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
            response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
            payload.extend(response['Items'])
```

No puedo ayudarte con c#, pero en python así se obtienen todos los items de la tabla. Saludos